# ¿cual es la diferencia entre estos direccionamientos en laravel?

Tags: laravel

soy nuevo en laravel y me gustaria saber cual es la diferencia entre estas dos formas de redireccionar y envio de mensaje en laravel.
Primera forma:

```
Session::flash('message','Usuario actualizado correctamente');
return redirect::to('/usuario');
```

Segunda forma:

```
return redirect('/usuario')->with('message','Usuario actualizado correctamente');
```

Comment: La [documentación de laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4) siempre nos provee de toda la informacion que necesitamos, lo digo por experiencia propia, solo hay que leer un poco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ambos funcionan de la misma manera.

**En la Primera:**

> Session::flash('message','Usuario actualizado correctamente'); return redirect::to('/usuario');

La [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#flash-data) dice:

> Datos Flash
>
> A veces puede que desee almacenar elementos en la sesión sólo para la siguiente solicitud. Puede hacerlo utilizando el método flash. Los datos almacenados en la sesión utilizando este método sólo estarán disponibles durante la solicitud HTTP subsiguiente y, a continuación, se eliminarán..

Esto quiere decir que almacena los datos flash para cuando redirecciones.

A diferencia de la segunda, puedes hacer una condición con distintos flash y luego redireccionar. Ejemplo:

```
$exists = false;
if($exists){
   Session::flash('message','Usuario actualizado correctamente');
}else{
   Session::flash('message','Error al actualizar Usuario');
}
return redirect::to('/usuario');
```

**En la Segunda:**

> return redirect('/usuario')->with('message','Usuario actualizado correctamente');

La [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data) dice:

> Redireccionamiento con Flashed Session Data
>
> La redirección a una nueva URL y Flashed Session Data se realiza normalmente al mismo tiempo.

Esto quiere decir que envía a la nueva URL la data que le quieras enviar al sesión, a diferencia de la primera, no puedes crear condiciones para distintos flash, a menos que hagas distintos redireccionamientos. Ejemplo:

```
$exists = false;
if($exists){
   return redirect('/usuario')->with('message','Usuario actualizado correctamente');
}else{
   return redirect('/usuario')->with('message','Error al actualizar Usuario');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

En adición a la respuesta de Pablo, voy a agregar el código donde se muestra que ambos métodos utilizan el mismo código, tanto la redirección como la forma de pasar datos a la sesión.

En cuanto a la redirección, el primer código mostrado en la pregunta llama este método:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.php#L103

```
/**
 * Create a new redirect response to the given path.
 *
 * @param  string  $path
 * @param  int     $status
 * @param  array   $headers
 * @param  bool    $secure
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function to($path, $status = 302, $headers = [], $secure = null)
{
    return $this->createRedirect($this->generator->to($path, [], $secure), $status, $headers);
}
```

A continuación el código que es llamado por la segunda parte de la pregunta. Aquí básicamente se está llamando a la función `to()` que es la que el OP utiliza en el primer código que se muestra y que está justo antes de este texto.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L645

```
if (! function_exists('redirect')) {
    /**
     * Get an instance of the redirector.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $to
     * @param  int     $status
     * @param  array   $headers
     * @param  bool    $secure
     * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Redirector|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    function redirect($to = null, $status = 302, $headers = [], $secure = null)
    {
        if (is_null($to)) {
            return app('redirect');
        }
        return app('redirect')->to($to, $status, $headers, $secure);
    }
}
```

---

En cuanto a la forma de pasar datos temporalmente a la sesión, el primer código utiliza este método:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php#L333

```
/**
 * Flash a key / value pair to the session.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @param  mixed   $value
 * @return void
 */
public function flash($key, $value)
{
    $this->put($key, $value);
    $this->push('_flash.new', $key);
    $this->removeFromOldFlashData([$key]);
}
```

El segundo método, al igual que en la redirección, hace un llamado al código mostrado en la primera parte:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Http/RedirectResponse.php#L35

```
/**
 * Flash a piece of data to the session.
 *
 * @param  string|array  $key
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function with($key, $value = null)
{
    $key = is_array($key) ? $key : [$key => $value];
    foreach ($key as $k => $v) {
        $this->session->flash($k, $v);
    }
    return $this;
```

---

En resumen, **la diferencia entre las dos formas de redireccionar es practicamente ninguna, salvo que la segunda incluye "un paso más" al llamar una función más.**

---

La diferencia entre las dos formas de pasar datos a la sesión, aparte de lo que ya señaló Pablo, es que **la primera solo permite pasar "un dato", mientras en la segunda se puede pasar un array de datos como se puede ver en el código**.